# php update radio button state in db

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, insert-update

I am new in php, I just starting learn php and have some problems.
In admin panel I have some form for adding info, after that in output I have radio buttons for selecting which row show into website. The problem is in update function the query is ok but it doesn't work, and I need you help.

thanks.

submit if.

```
 if(isset($_POST['update_info'])){
        $selected_info=$_POST['selected'];
        $selected_id = $_POST['id'];
        updateHomeInfo($selected_info, $selected_id);
    }
```

output added rows.

```
<div class="home-output">
        <form action="/admin/" method="post">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>#</td>
                        <td>slected</td>
                        <td>title</td>
                        <td>descriptiom</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($homeInfo as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="selected" value="home-info" <?php if($row['selected'] == 1) echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="clear_info" value="delete all">
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="update_info" value="update">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and update function.

```
function updateHomeInfo($selected_info, $selected_id) {
    global $db;
    $db->exec("UPDATE home SET selected = '$selected_info' where id = '$selected_id'");
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's in the `selected` column? The `UPDATE` query sets it to the string `home-info` because that comes from the form, but the loop that displays the `checked` attribute looks for `$row['selected'] == 1`. So is it a string or a number?

Comment: @Barmar it's boolean true or false(1 or 0)

Comment: Then what's going on in the `UPDATE` statement? Why is it setting it to `$selected_info`?

Comment: Also, when you set it to 1 in the selected row, shouldn't you also set it to 0 in all the other rows?

Comment: yes  and how to do that?

Comment: LIke I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your hidden inputs have the same name; they'll all be submitted, and the value of `$_POST['id']` will just be the last one, not the one next to the selected radio button. And all the radio buttons have the same value as well.

You should put the ID into the value of the radio button. You only need one copy of the hidden input, and it can contain the selected info.

```
<form action="/admin/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="home-info">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        ...
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        <td><input type="radio" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" <?php if($row['selected'] == 1) echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
        ...
```

Actually, it seems like you don't need the `selected` input at all, if `selected` is a boolean. It should just be:

```
function updateHomeInfo($selected_id) {
    $db->exec("UPDATE home SET selected = (id = '$selected_id')");
}
```

This will set `selected` to `1` for the selected ID, and `0` for all the other IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much it's work, and also if no hard can you explain the query how it works because I didn't understand it :)

Comment: `id = '$selected_id'` is true on the row that matches `$selected_id`, false on all other rows. `true = 1` and `false = 0`, so it sets the `selected` field to those values.

Comment: then we didn't need hidden input yes?

Comment: That's what I said in my answer.